# Question regarding a Jacobian

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have these two pairs of variables:
\begin{equation}
u = g_1(x,y), \qquad v = g_2(x,y),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x = h_1(u,v), \qquad y = h_2(u,v).
\end{equation}
If my jacobian of $x$ and $y$, $J(x,y)$ is the determinant of the partial derivatives of the functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, could I then say that the Jacobian of $u$ and $v$ is $J(u,v) = 1/J(h_1(u,v),h_2(u,v))$ or is this not true?

I am reading a portion of my statistics book and was not sure if this is just coincidence or is it a fact. The example shows that the Jacobian for going from polar to Cartesian coordinates is $1/r$, and I know that from Cartesian to polar the Jacobian is $r$ so I wasn't sure if this was a coincidence or not.

Comment: Hint: the Jacobian of the inverse of a function is the matrix inverse if its Jacobian.

Comment: @AlexMardikian: Have you got the answer? +1

Comment: Been a bit busy with my classes. Will be working out my questions I haven't accepted an answer for yet this weekend then accepting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, we can porve the following alternatively:
$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,s)}=\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(r,s)}$$  Here we assume that $x=f(u,v), y=g(u,v)$ and $u=\phi(r,s),~v=\psi(r,s)$

The point I can hint you is to do the definition of Jacobian to get the right path. Look for the case $x=r,y=s$ next.

Comment: Where are you, my friend? ;-)